# res.Send it results in 404 error?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Hi I am trying display the message : respond with a resource from routes folder/user.js

```
  exports.list = function (req, res) {
  res.send("respond with a resource");
  };
```

But I am getting an error 404 in command prompt.And in url
 localhost:8080\user where the response is sent I get the message:

Cannot GET /user

my app.js has code:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

The example I am working on is from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czmulJ9NBP0. and time is at 1.37.41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is named `/users` *not* `/user`. So try navigating to `/users` in your browser instead and it should work.

Comment: I would suggest changing to app.get('/user', user.list);